# cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, jsp, http-authentication

I am trying to use HTTP Authentication in my JSP code. But I am getting error on MyAuthenticator cannot be resolved to a type. Is the sytax correct for the code that I have writtent in jsp page. Any suggestions will be appreciated..

```
    <%@ page language="java" import="java.net.Authenticator,java.net.PasswordAuthentication,java.io.BufferedReader,java.net.*,java.io.*" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%

String urlToQuery = request.getParameter("url");
System.out.println(" " +urlToQuery);
//URL url = new URL(urlToQuery);



//InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();

String urlString = "";
String username = "";
String password = "";
Authenticator.setDefault(new MyAuthenticator(username, password));
URL url = new URL(urlToQuery);
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
InputStream content = (InputStream) url.getContent();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
String line;
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println(line);
}
System.out.println("Done.");

 class MyAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
    private String username, password;

    public MyAuthenticator(String user, String pass) {
      username = user;
      password = pass;
    }

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
      System.out.println("Requesting Host  : " + getRequestingHost());
      System.out.println("Requesting Port  : " + getRequestingPort());
      System.out.println("Requesting Prompt : " + getRequestingPrompt());
      System.out.println("Requesting Protocol: " + getRequestingProtocol());
      System.out.println("Requesting Scheme : " + getRequestingScheme());
      System.out.println("Requesting Site  : " + getRequestingSite());
      return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray());
    }
  }



%>

<%=line %>
```

Comment: Where is the import declaration for MyAuthenticator?

Comment: @adarshr, I think MyAuthenticator will be coming in Authenticator and I have included the import for Authenticator.. right?? And syntax is correct for the code that I have written in jsp??

Comment: @adarshr, he has defined the class inside the JSP... look further down.

Comment: @SJuan76 - Oh yeah, never spotted that! Not at all a good place to define classes though.

Comment: @adarshr, Can you provide example based on my code.. how to do http authentication..That will be of great help to me..

Comment: @Raihan Jamal - Please see SJuan76's answer. That is quite a give away.

Comment: Just do not write Java code in a JSP file instead of a normal Java class. Putting Java code in a normal Java class will fix all your problems, now and in the future. Write only HTML/CSS/JS/taglibs/EL in JSP. Start learning servlets. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Answer (score 0):

Do not define inner classes in JSPs. Consider a JSP like a simple method.

A JSP is something like(1):

```
public class MyJSP extends Servlet {
  public void service(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response) {
     /** JSP CODE HERE **/
  }
}
```

Defining an inner class should be done as an anonimous inner class:

```
 Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
   protected getPasswordAuthentication() {
     System.out.println("Requesting Host  : " + getRequestingHost());
     System.out.println("Requesting Port  : " + getRequestingPort());
     ...
   }
 });
```

Not sure what would I do to pass parameters (I only have used the simplest anonymous inner classes).

Anyway for anything that is going to be used from outside methods, I would use a public class (in its own file) and avoid all these troubles.

(1)Not exactly this, but you get the idea.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. Can you explain me by giving the example from my code.. As I am not able to grasp this.. As I am new to these thing.. It will be of great help to me..

Comment: Sure... delete everything and learn how to code a simple console java app (lots of tutorial in the web) so you learn the basic concepts of java (classes, visibility, and so many more) before trying to use a frameworks that require that you are used to these concepts. You are welcome.

Comment: It would be possible to define an inner class on a JSP page by using the JSP declaration construction `<%! ... %>`. Please keep you answers constructive.

Answer (score 0):

`<% ... %>` leads JSP to treat the code contents as statements. Therefore you class becomes a local class following the same scope rules as local variables (that is, you must declare the class earlier than using it). I didn't test it, but if you rewrite your code to:

```
    <%@ page language="java" import="java.net.Authenticator,java.net.PasswordAuthentication,java.io.BufferedReader,java.net.*,java.io.*" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%

class MyAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
    private String username, password;

    public MyAuthenticator(String user, String pass) {
      username = user;
      password = pass;
    }

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
      System.out.println("Requesting Host  : " + getRequestingHost());
      System.out.println("Requesting Port  : " + getRequestingPort());
      System.out.println("Requesting Prompt : " + getRequestingPrompt());
      System.out.println("Requesting Protocol: " + getRequestingProtocol());
      System.out.println("Requesting Scheme : " + getRequestingScheme());
      System.out.println("Requesting Site  : " + getRequestingSite());
      return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray());
    }
  }

String urlToQuery = request.getParameter("url");
System.out.println(" " +urlToQuery);
//URL url = new URL(urlToQuery);



//InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();

String urlString = "";
String username = "";
String password = "";
Authenticator.setDefault(new MyAuthenticator(username, password));
URL url = new URL(urlToQuery);
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
InputStream content = (InputStream) url.getContent();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
String line;
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println(line);
}
System.out.println("Done.");





%>

<%=line %>
```

Then `MyAuthenticator` should be resolvable in your code.

Consider moving the Java class to a separate file to make your code more readable.